# Making update notice functionality for my Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I've created one of my Plugin.I want to add update functionality through api

The notice should be visible when I use the Plugin, if required for Plugin update

Actually i have no idea so please give me your suggestion or give me a code,so i can add functionality for update Plugin.

> Note : If you have a no idea for api so you can provide another code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will Complete this Coding See here,

```
add_filter ( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'plugin_check_for_update' );

function plugin_check_for_update ( $transient ) {

    // Check Plugin is active or not.
    if ( empty( $transient->checked['PLUGIN-NAME/PLUGIN-NAME.php'] ) ) {

      return $transient;
    }

    $request = plugin_fetch_data_of_latest_version();

    if ( is_wp_error( $request ) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request ) != 200 ) {
        return $transient;
    } else {
        $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    }

    $data = json_decode( $response );

    if ( version_compare( $transient->checked['PLUGIN-NAME/PLUGIN-NAME.php'], $data->new_version, '<' ) ) {
        $transient->response['PLUGIN-NAME/PLUGIN-NAME.php'] = $data;
    }
    return $transient;
}

function plugin_fetch_data_of_latest_version() {

    // API call to check for new version
    $request = wp_safe_remote_get( 'YOUR-API' );

    return $request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me one second on Google. Do you already tried the `plugin-update-checker` by Yahnis Elsts? See here: [YahnisElsts / plugin-update-checker](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker)

Comment: Sorry but i am not using third party plugin i want to custom code But it's OK i will completed this coding.see here